# Loop VBA through multiple files

Tags: vba, powerpoint

below I have some code which finds and replaces a certain word. However, my knowledge of VBA is limited so I don't know how to loop this code through multiple Powerpoint files in a folder and save them. Also it only takes words written on the first sheet, I don't know what's up with that?

```
Sub DemoFindReplace()
Dim sld As Slide
Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
If shp.HasTextFrame Then
    If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "TEST", "REPLACE")
    End If
End If
Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: Please be aware that your code will break the formatting of all text boxes unless they contain no internal differences in font, boldness, etc..

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear whet you're asking, but if you want to loop through a number of files the below code will help:

```
Dim MyFile, MyPath, MyName As String 
' Returns "WIN.INI" if it exists.
MyFile = Dir("C:\WINDOWS\WIN.INI")   

' Returns filename with specified extension. If more than one *.INI 
' file exists, the first file found is returned.
MyFile = Dir("C:\WINDOWS\*.INI")

' Call Dir again without arguments to return the next *.INI file in the 
' same directory.
MyFile = Dir()

' Return first *.TXT file, including files with a set hidden attribute.
MyFile = Dir("*.TXT", vbHidden)

' Display the names in C:\ that represent directories.
MyPath = "c:\"   ' Set the path.
MyName = Dir(MyPath, vbDirectory)   ' Retrieve the first entry.
Do While MyName <> ""   ' Start the loop.
      ' Use bitwise comparison to make sure MyName is a directory. 
      If (GetAttr(MyPath & MyName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then 
         ' Display entry only if it's a directory.
         MsgBox(MyName)
      End If   
   MyName = Dir()   ' Get next entry.
Loop
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx